# jwrapper online Windows fails with https updateurl

Tags: java, windows, jwrapper

I've used jwrapper to package an app for linux, osx, and windows. It works fine on linux and osx. On windows it fails w/o giving any information to the user, and logs a download failure for the JRE version.txt file.

From the jwrapper log and the apache log it appears the jwrapper windows client is hitting port 443 with an http request, which, of course, fails.

The UpdateURL is https. Is there anything else I can do to ask jwrapper to make an https connection? I suspect this is just a bug. I tried 00031607960 and 00033253833.

Comment: This appears to be a simple bug, we are looking into a fix and will put up a new JW release soon.  Thanks for notifying us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, this issue was apparently fixed in JWrapper version 00034804310 released Mar 24, 2015. I haven't tested it, but it is listed in the [release notes](http://www.jwrapper.com/jwrapper-release-history.html) as being fixed.

http://www.jwrapper.com/download.html